# Finding all roots of $x^6 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^4 + 3 x^2 + 6 x + 6$, knowing that one root is $x=-1+i$.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find all roots of
>   $$V(x) = x^6 + 2 x^5 + 2 x^4 + 3 x^2 + 6 x + 6$$
>   knowing that one root is $x=-1+i$.

Sorry for the picture. I found two roots of the polynomial and also found an equation which can help me to find all of the rest. Can someone help me what do I need to do next?

[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 2):

To solve $$x^2+2x+2=0$$ use $$x^2+2x+1=-1$$ hence $$(x+1)^2=-1$$ which gives the solutions $\ -1-i\ $ and $\ -1+i\ $

To solve $$x^4+3=0$$ first note that the absolute value of the solutions must be $3^{\frac{1}{4}}$ and then use the $4$ fourth roots of $-1$ , being $$\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$$ which , multiplied with $3^{\frac{1}{4}}$, give the $4$ other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

One factor is $$x^2+2x+2=0$$ which can be solved by the quadratic formula. Solving $$x^4+3=0$$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot3^{1/4}(1+i),\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot3^{1/4}(1-i),\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot3^{1/4}(-1+i),\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2}\cdot3^{1/4}(-1-i)$$
Substituting $$x^2=t$$ then we get $$t^2+(\sqrt{3})^2=0$$ By the formula $$a^2+b^2=(a+bi)(a-bi)$$ you will get the solutions.

Comment: Can you show how did you solve it? I'm quite confused